# CupertinoTabView casusing Assertion failed: _history.isNotEmpty is not true on Navigator.pop() (web only)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-cupertino

So I have an app that Pops the current screen once an event happens. The code works fine on iOS and Android. But on the web I get the following error:

```dart
Assertion failed:
..\…\widgets\navigator.dart:5083
_history.isNotEmpty
is not true
```

The debug dialog shows how points the CupertinoTabView of the current tab in the stack. The navigation is to the root page of the Tab view. The `tabBuilder`:

```dart
(context, index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              navigatorKey: tabOneKey,
              builder: (context) {
                return tabs[index];
              },
            );

            break;
          case 1:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              navigatorKey: tabTwoKey,
              builder: (context) {
                return tabs[index];
              },
            );

            break;
          case 2:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              navigatorKey: tabThreeKey,
              builder: (context) {
                return tabs[index];
              },
            );

            break;
          case 3:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              navigatorKey: tabFourKey,
              builder: (context) {
                return tabs[index];
              },
            );

            break;
          default:
            return Container();
        }
      }
```

I have tried Wrapping the `Navigator.pop()` in `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`. The same error happens on web. It changes nothing on mobile. What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

the navigator work like stack, pop will remove the last page , push will add to the top , this error mean you are trying to remove the last page, but there is none , this can happen if you pop the previous pages after push like the following

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil( "pageName", (Route<dynamic> route) => false) ;
 Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

**Solution :**

first thing to do is don't wrap pop , use this instead if you are not sure if the navigator is empty or not  .

```
Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
```

and make sure you use the following  before any .pop() not pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed ("pageName") ;
```

Comment: I never went around to implementing this solution. If anybody who comes across this answer and implement it, comment with my tag. I will mark it as the answer